# How would you get a Material UI transition component to completely fill its parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to get a Material UI transition component to completely fill its parent component. I had partial success by styling its width and height to 100% and translating it on the Y axis the correct number of pixels. However, after the transition is opened, closed, and re-opened, it no longer takes its original shape of filling the entire parent div and looks like the following:
[image]

The following is the code for this component. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
  const Item = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    expanded ? setExpanded(false) : setExpanded(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box className={classes.item} onClick={handleClick}>
        <ChatIcon className={classes.itemIcon}/>
        <Typography className={classes.itemTitle}>{props.title}</Typography>
        <Grow in={expanded} style={{backgroundColor: "blue", width: "100%", height: "100%", position: "relative", transform: `translateY(${-141}px)`}}>
          <Box>
            <Typography className={classes.itemBodyText}>{props.body}</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grow>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

Existing CSS:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  textBox: {
    width: "100%",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.secondary.main} !important`,
    padding: 10
  },
  bodyText: {
      color: `${theme.palette.white} !important`,
      maxWidth: 1000,
      margin: "0 auto",
      paddingBottom: 40,
      fontSize: 16,
      paddingLeft: 20,
      paddingRight: 20
  },
  item: {
    width: 350,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  heading: {
    paddingTop: 40,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 50,
    lineHeight: 1.7
  },
  itemIcon: {
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    margin: 20
  },
  carousel: {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }
}));
```

Comment: Could you also include the css you already have.

Comment: @Hypothesis Sorry about that, its added now!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was dumb and overthinking this. It's as easy as not using transform and using the top and left attributes shown here:

```
const Item = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    expanded ? setExpanded(false) : setExpanded(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box className={classes.item} onClick={handleClick}>
        <ChatIcon className={classes.itemIcon}/>
        <Typography className={classes.itemTitle}>{props.title}</Typography>
        <Grow in={expanded} style={{backgroundColor: "blue", width: "100%", height: "100%", position: "relative", transform: `translateY(${-141}px)`}}>
          <Box>
            <Typography className={classes.itemBodyText}>{props.body}</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grow>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```